# Sql Server unexpected Cartesian Product

Tags: sql-server-2008

This is SQL Server 2008.  I have these two tables and a join:

```
DECLARE @EmployeeCrossDay TABLE
(
    EmployeeId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
    WorkDate DATE, OtherStuff...
)

DECLARE @ET TABLE
(
    EmployeeId      UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    WorkDate        DATE, DifferentOtherStuff...
)

SELECT *
FROM @EmployeeCrossDay ecd
LEFT JOIN @ET et ON et.EmployeeId = ecd.EmployeeId
    AND et.WorkDate = ecd.WorkDate
```

The first table has 5,680 rows (one for each employee for each date in a range), the second has 397 (one or more for each day that the employee actually worked).  (Thus, EmployeeId/WorkDate is a unique combination in the first table, but not in the second.) The results of my query are correct (a list of each employee with one or more rows for days he worked and a row for each day he didn't work), but it takes about 3 seconds and my profile shows a Cartesian product along the way (2,254,960 rows).  Is there a way to restructure this query to prevent the complete cross join?

*** EDITED ***
After adding the primary keys, as suggested, Set Showplan_Text On gives me this:

```
  |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1007]=isnull(@ET.[StartTime] as [et].[StartTime],[Expr1010]), [Expr1008]=isnull(@ET.[EndTime] as [et].[EndTime],[Expr1010])))
       |--Nested Loops(Left Outer Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([et].[ServiceCallId]))
            |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1006]=isnull(@ET.[TypeId] as [et].[TypeId],(8)), [Expr1009]=isnull(@ET.[Interrupt] as [et].[Interrupt],($0.0000))))
            |    |--Nested Loops(Left Outer Join, WHERE:(@ET.[EmployeeId] as [et].[EmployeeId]=@EmployeeCrossDay.[EmployeeId] as [ecd].[EmployeeId] AND @ET.[WorkDate] as [et].[WorkDate]=@EmployeeCrossDay.[WorkDate] as [ecd].[WorkDate]))
            |         |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1010]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(datetime,@EmployeeCrossDay.[WorkDate] as [ecd].[WorkDate],0)))
            |         |    |--Sort(ORDER BY:([ecd].[Number] ASC, [ecd].[WorkDate] ASC))
            |         |         |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:(@EmployeeCrossDay AS [ecd]))
            |         |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:(@ET AS [et]))
            |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([Snapper].[dbo].[ServiceCalls].[PK_Jobs] AS [sc]), SEEK:([sc].[ServiceCallId]=@ET.[ServiceCallId] as [et].[ServiceCallId]) ORDERED FORWARD)
```

What I mean by "shows a Cartesian product along the way" comes from setting Statistics Profile on.  It shows too much to paste in here, but for the next to last item in the plan (Clustered Index Scan), it shows 2,254,960 (my commas) under Rows and 5680 under Executes.  Am I misreading that to say I have a Cartesian product?

Comment: Add a primary key to each table?

Comment: I added `PRIMARY KEY( EmployeeId, WorkDate )` to the first table and `EmployeeTimeId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY` to the second table.  My execution time fell to sub-second, which is great (Thanks!), but the interim Cartesian product is still there!  Kinda makes it hard to worry about it, huh?

Comment: Did you try using a query hint?  Add "Option (HASH JOIN, MERGE JOIN)" at the end of the query.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the phrase "my profile shows a Cartesian product along the way". Can you post the actual execution plans?

Comment: @MartinSmith I have edited the question to show the plan and explain what I mean by "Cartesian product along the way".

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'll have to read up on what that does, but I tried it and it worked like a charm.  It reduced all my Executes to 1 and removed the need to define Primary Keys.  My timings are not sophisticated, but once I got under a second, I was happy.

Comment: @KellyCline - There is no index on `@ET` that it can use to seek into on `EmployeeId` so it is doing 5680 full table scans. It probably chooses the nested loops plan as it assumes that operations on table variables will just emit one row. You could add an `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` hint to get it to take account of the actual cardinality. Also you could add a constraint to the table variable with leading column `EmployeeId` to provide a useful index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got three good answers, but they all came as comments, so I am posting 'the' answer here.

Aaron suggested that I add a primary key to each table var.  I added

```
EmployeeTimeId  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY
```

to @ET and

```
PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeId, WorkDate)
```

to @EmployeeCrossDay because, in both cases, EmployeeId was not unique.

Even though EmpmloyeeTimeId was not involved in the join, this alone reduce my query from over 3 seconds to under 1.  However, my Statistics Profile showed that one of the steps in the execution plan was running 5680 times and hitting over 2.2 million rows (5,680 * 397).  Even though the response time was acceptable, I was curious about that.

Martin then suggested that my key for @ET needed to have EmployeeId leading.  So I replaced the key with

```
PRIMARY KEY( EmployeeId, EmployeeTimeId )
```

At this point, the execution plan showed the former cross join reduced to hitting only 397 rows (instead of over 2 million), even though it was still doing the process for each @ET row (5680), it was now doing a clustered index seek instead of a full table scan.

Along the way, Gordon suggested adding

```
OPTION( HASH JOIN, MERGE JOIN )
```

I removed all my previously applied indexes and no step in the resulting plan executed more than once.

All three suggestions returned the same data in under a second, so I gave points (and now, my thanks) to each one.